# Lifting Free Group Actions on $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, group-actions, covering-spaces, free-groups

The free group $F_2$ acts faithfully on the circle $S^1$ by homeomorphisms.  Someone told me that given any such action on $S^1$, we can lift it to a faithful action $F_2\curvearrowright \mathbb{R}$ by homeomorphisms.  Why isn't there an obstruction?  It seems to me like we should have to worry about lifts composing correctly.

Comment: I would suspect that action on the circle via homeomorphism would induce an action on the universal cover due to the local homeomorphism property of the covering map.

Comment: @Justin That's not the case in general.  For example, you can make a finite cyclic group act faithfully on $S^1$ by rotations, but every non-trivial homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite order.  So the finite group can't act faithfully on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see. Considering this is a free group, that might prevent that issue, and allow for the lifting to work out.

Answer (score 4):

We don't have to worry about lifts composing correctly because the group is free, so there aren't any relations to worry about!  Letting $a$ and $b$ be the generators of $F_2$ acting on $S^1$, we can lift them to homeomorphisms $\bar{a},\bar{b}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Then $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ generate an action of $F_2$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which is a lift of our action on $S^1$.  This action is faithful since the action in $S^1$ is faithful.

A bit more abstractly, let $G$ be the group of homeomorphisms of $S^1$ and let $H$ be the group of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ that descend to a homeomorphism of $S^1$.  There is a homomorphism $p:H\to G$, taking an element of $H$ to the element of $G$ it descends to.  Since every element of $G$ can be lifted to a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$, $p$ is surjective.

Now, our faithful action on $S^1$ is just an injective homomorphism $f:F_2\to G$.  If $a$ and $b$ are the generators of $F_2$, pick $x,y\in H$ such that $p(x)=f(a)$ and $p(y)=f(b)$ and let $g:F_2\to H$ be the unique homomorphism such that $g(a)=x$ and $g(b)=y$.  Then $pg=f$ (since they agree on $a$ and $b$), so $g$ is a lift of our action to $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $f$ is injective and $pg=f$, $g$ is injective too, so the lifted action is faithful.